# What is a "Linker state" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

If I type `:show linker` in blank ghci, I get for example

```
----- Linker state -----
Pkgs: [base-4.14.1.0, integer-gmp-1.0.3.0, ghc-prim-0.6.1, rts-1.0]
Objs: []
BCOs: []
```

What does those terms mean? These are not modules, because I haven't loaded any and if I type `:show modules` then there is nothing.
From C++ I know that linker link object files to make a final program, so why it is present in interactive mode, where we don't compile one big program, just a bunch of single functions?

Comment: `base` is always loaded since that provides the `Prelude`. The other modules are dependends. `integer-gmp` is used for arbitrary large `Integer`s, `ghc-prim` is more or less how the compiler wires Haskell logic to a machine implementation.

Comment: So those are modules after all? Why they don't come up with `:show modules`?

Comment: no these are *packages*. But these are packages that are "hardwired" in the compiler. Since eventually the compiler needs to perform additions/multiplications/... on the CPU.